# Google App Engine - CNAME for Image API URLS

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am working with App Engine to store and serve images from Cloudstorage. I am using the API documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) to create URLS that serve the image directly from Google without passing through my app. To get the URLS I am using `get_serving_url()` which returns a URL on the `ggpht.com` domain.

All of this is working well, but I would rather use my own subdomain for serving the images. As documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris), this is possible for CGS buckets accessed through `googleapis.com` but when serving images from googleapis.com you can't transform the image on the fly by adding arguments to the url.

The [documentation for the Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) says:

> If you supply the arguments, this method returns a URL encoded with
>   the arguments specified. If you do not supply any arguments, this
>   method returns the default URL for the image, for example:
>
> `http://your_app_id.appspot.com/randomStringImageId`

which suggests that it is possible to get a URL on the `appspot.com` domain rather than the `ggpht.com` This would be perfect because I can set up a CNAME for the appspot domain. Sadly, I can't figure out how to make one of the URLS the documentation promises.

Is it possible to get the best of both worlds? Images on my own subdomain served through the images api mechanism that allows on-the-fly manipulation via url arguments?

Comment: before looking into this further, be aware that you will never be able to server HTTPS from your custom domain linked to GCS

Comment: Thanks Koma, I _think_ that will be okay. They are just public images.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the lines carefully in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/), you will find that they have mentioned clearly that The URL returned by this method (get_serving_URL()) is **always public**, but not guessable; **private URLs are not currently
supported**. I think your trying to use the private URLs to serve that image which is not possible for now.Might be in the future they are planning to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure what I wrote that makes you think I'm trying to use private URLs. I simply want my images to be served from my own domain. There are a lot of reasons a person may want to do this: one is making it easy to determine where an image is coming from simply by looking at the address. I am currently serving a website at photo-mark.com, but all the images are coming from ggpht.com. That's less than ideal.

Comment: @MarkM: I misunderstood because I think you want to change the publicURL which is lh3.gghpt.com with your name such as pics.photo-mark.com. For your question, you need the Public URL to serve that image as it is not possible for you to serve that image from appspot.com if you want transformation on the fly.

Comment: However, you serve the transformed image from the blob store without using any instance hours given in the document [1]. There is also a better way to do is the use of the Image class, to transform the image and after transformation serve that image on your domain.

[1]  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Serving_a_blob